# Does Vishwaksena, the army-chief of Vishnu, appear only in Puranas?

Tags: vishwaksena

I don't think he is mentioned in the Ramayana.  In the Mahabharata, Vishwaksena is a name of Krishna/Vishnu.  Before his final defeat, Bhishma says

> In the battle, the brave and intelligent one, the destroyer of the cities of enemies, began to
> think. ‘I am capable of slaying all the Pandavas with a single bow, had
> the immensely strong Vishvaksena not been their protector now."

There are other minor characters named Vishwaksena, not the chief of Vishnu's army.

Answer (score 4):

Even in Valmiki Ramayana, 'Vishwaksena' is a name of Vishnu -

> *' O Raghava ! You are the truth in the middle and at the end. You are supreme Dharma in the worlds. **You are Vishwaksena.***'

- Valmiki Ramayana Critical Edition Chapter 6 (105)

Comment: Is Chapter 6 from Yuddha Kaand? For a person like me who is reading authentic Valmiki Ramayana, it would be easy to find this verse.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto - No. It's chapter 105 of 6th Kanda ( yuddha kanda) of Critical edition of Valmiki Ramayana.

Comment: In chapter 105, Rishi Agastya gives Aditya hridaya stotra to Shree Rama, and in whole chapter he extols Surya devata not Rama in authentic Valmiki Ramayana.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto - I am talking about the critical edition of Valmiki Ramayana. In non-critical editions, chapter numbers may be different.

Comment: Can you help me with the context in critical edition in chapter 105?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto - It's during Sita's Agni pareeksha when gods came to Rama and praises him as Narayana.